# How to find image usage? Outliner / Data API / Images

Tags: image, outliner

[image: Founded packed image in Outliner / Data API]

I try to shrink downloaded FBX files, sometime I succeeded, sometimes not. I try to find out what image I could not unpacked. Now I realize there are images what are packed in there (bleder file) but I could not see in the material properties. Where are they, how I unpack them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are possibly two different questions :).

1. To unpack an image, go to *Image Editor* and click the *Unpack* icon.
2. To remove *unused* images, select all and *RMB > Clear Fake User*.
   All *unused* images will be removed after reopening your .blend file.
   Only images that are currently in use will stay in the .blend file.

*Unpacking a file*

[image]

*Removing images not in use*

[image]